# List array bind ListView and update data and ListView stick

Tags: android, listview

My code:

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this.Context, Arraylist, R.layout.activity_lxxx_show, 
new String[]
{
"_id", "line_id", "sort_order", "station_name", "status", 
"Top_colour", "Bottom_colour", "Left_colour", "Right_colour"
}, 
new int[]
{
R.id._id, R.id.tv_line_id, R.id.tv_sort_order, R.id.tv_station_name, R.id.tv_status, 
R.id.imageView_Top, R.id.imageView_Bottom, R.id.imageView_Left, R.id.imageView_Right
});
lv = (ListView) this.Context.findViewById(R.id.listView_lxxx);
lv.setAdapter(adapter); //display data in ListView

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I need to call this code repeat in a period of time. I want to bind the different Arraylist data to Adapter. It can update data currently.

But ListView sticks automatic. Stick is that when I slide LIstView to the bottom, ListView bind the data again and display on the top of ListView.

How to solve the problem? How could I control ListView?

Comment: post some code what your doing to append data to adaptor.

Answer (score 0):

don't repeat creating of listview and adapter. If you repeat creating listview and adaptor the displaying list will be a new list and it will show the top of the listview instead of current position. So create list and adapter once and when ever you wants to bind new items to the list just update the data of the adapter and call like below.

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

please check the example which i am posting below.

```
public class GrowingListViewActivity extends ListActivity implements OnScrollListener  {
Aleph0 adapter = new Aleph0();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);
}

public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisible, int visibleCount,
        int totalCount) {

    boolean loadMore = /* maybe add a padding */
    firstVisible + visibleCount >= totalCount;

    if (loadMore) {
        adapter.count += visibleCount; // or any other amount
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView v, int s) {
}

class Aleph0 extends BaseAdapter {

    int count = 40; /* starting amount */

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    public View getView(int pos, View v, ViewGroup p) {
        TextView view = new TextView(GrowingListViewActivity.this);
        view.setText("entry View : " + pos);
        return view;
    }
}
}
```

I think this will help you.